# Finishing activity when back button is pressed (Alert Dialog)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm working on an app which parses some json into a listview (background). I'm currently trying to deal with the errors when data is unavailable to populate the listview.

I have handled this in the onPostExecute method by creating an Alert Dialog as shown in the code below

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            //Shows alert dialog if data is unavailable

            if(args != null && args.equals(noData)){
                 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(JsonActivity.this);
                 builder.setTitle("Title");
                 builder.setMessage(noData);
                 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                 alert.show();

            }


        }
```

This works fine but if I click the back button it leads back to an unpopulated blank list view.

I would like to finish the activity if the backbutton is pressed when the alert dialog is shown.

I also tried overriding the onBackPressed method but it did not work.

```
        @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        JsonActivity.this.finish();
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: try to add a listener on your alert to receive the cancel or the dismiss action

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
...
builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // if from activity
        finish();
        // if activity is a field
        //activity.finish();
    }

});
```

**onCancel** is fired if your dialog is cancelable on back button is pressed when it is shown.

or use an OnDismissListener that will be called whenever the Dialog is dismissed no matter if you press some button or back button

```
...
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        finish();
    }
});
alert.show();
```

And it is usually a better practice to show a Toast if no Data instead of dialg.

```
        if(args != null && args.equals(noData)){
             Toast.makeText(context, noData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             finish();
        }
```

Comment: the first option works perfectly thank you. By the way why is it better practice to show a toast instead of dialog. I chose the dialog because it looked better.